# How do I create an ActiveAdmin filter for a comma separated list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a standard rails User model. I am trying to add a filter which allows me to input a comma separated list of User.id values and return the results.

In production I have 10s of thousands of users so a select filter, even with a collection is not desirable:

```
filter :id, as: :select

filter :id, as: :select, collection: User.where(role_id: 3)
```

Both of those return far too many rows for the Admin UI to perform well. Further I really need to input a list from somewhere else.

In the UI I need to enter a comma separated list like:

```
1,2,10,101,500,10000
```

Then get back only the Users matching the list of IDs.

It seems like a ransacker filter is the answer, but I am having trouble formating it.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309759/activeadmin-how-to-filter-for-strings-that-match-two-or-more-search-terms