# Activeadmin: how to filter for strings that match two or more search terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, ransack

Let's say I've got User class with an :email field. And let's say I'm using activeadmin to manage Users.

Making a filter that returns emails that match one string, e.g. "smith", is very simple.  In `admin/user.rb`, I just include the line

```
filter :email
```

This gives me a filter widget that does the job.

However, this filter doesn't let me search for the intersection of multiple terms. I can search for emails containing "smith", but not for emails containing both "smith" AND ".edu".

Google tells me that activerecord uses [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) under the hood, and the [Ransack demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search) has an 'advanced' mode that permits multiple term searches.

What's the easiest way to get a multiple term search widget into activeadmin?

Ideally, I'd like a widget that would allow me to enter `smith .edu` or `smith AND .edu` to filter for emails containing both terms.

Comment: This looks similar: http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/2e4ac6d6ff33/rails-active-admin-filter-for-multiple-words-search.html

Comment: to use mltiple field search you would use `filter :email_or_first_name_cont`. I think (never tried it, so am not even sure if it is logical to assume it will work) you could try `filter :email_or_email_cont` :)

Comment: I with it were this simple, but `filter :email_or_email_cont` doesn't seem to do the job. :(  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is simple solution using ranasckable scopes

So put something like this in your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    scope :email_includes, ->(search) {
       current_scope = self
       search.split.uniq.each do |word|
         current_scope = current_scope.where('user.email ILIKE ?', "%#{word}%")  
       end
       current_scope
    }

    def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
      [ :email_includes]
    end
end
```

After this you can add filter with AA DSL

Like

```
  filter :email_includes, as: :string, label: "Email"
```

UPD

should work if change `email_contains_any` to `email_includes`

Comment: These searches work when I run them in the console, but I can't make them work from activeadmin.  AA won't split the search string into an array of terms. I still need to use my custom AA fork. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @dB', for soem reasons we can't use ```_any```, change ```email_contains_any``` to ```email_includes```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  This works, and it's a much better solution than mine. Is this documented anywhere?  Do the activerecord docs explain how to do these multi-term searches?

Comment: it should be documented in ransack (AA just uses ransack), using ransackable scopes you can build any logic you want, not only multi-term searches ,and  yes I like it as well

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once! What I needed was the ability to filter by a list of email addresses, so I did   
`arr = search.downcase.split(/[ \n]/)` then   
`current_scope = current_scope.where(email: arr)`

Answer (score 6):

I've figured out a solution but it's not pretty.

The good news is that Ransack has no trouble with multiple terms searches. These searches use the 'predicate' `cont_all`. The following line works for finding emails containing 'smith' and '.edu'.

```
User.ransack(email_cont_all: ['smith','.edu'] ).result
```

Since these searches are easy in Ransack, they're probably straightforward in Activeadmin, right? Wrong! To get them working, I needed to do three things.

1. I put a custom ransack method (a.k.a. [ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers)) into `User.rb`. I named the ransacker `email_multiple_terms`.

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   # ...

   ransacker :email_multiple_terms do |parent|
     parent.table[:path]
   end
   ```
2. I declared a filter in my activeadmin dashboard, and associated it with the ransacker. Note that the search predicate `cont_all` is appended to the ransacker name.

`admin/User.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

# ...

filter :email_multiple_terms_cont_all, label: "Email", as: :string
```

This line creates the filter widget in Activeadmin. We're nearly there. One problem left: Activeadmin sends search queries to ransack as a single string (e.g. `"smith .edu"`), whereas our ransacker wants the search terms as an array. Somewhere, we need to convert the single string into an array of search terms.

3. I modified activeadmin to split the search string under certain conditions. The logic is in a method that I added to lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb.

   ```
   def split_search_params(params)
     params.keys.each do |key|
       if key.ends_with? "_any" or key.ends_with? "_all"
         params[key] = params[key].split  # turn into array
       end
     end
     params
   end
   ```

I then called this method inside `apply_filtering`.

```
    def apply_filtering(chain)
      @search = chain.ransack split_search_params clean_search_params params[:q]
      @search.result
    end
```

This code is live in my own fork of activeadmin, here: https://github.com/d-H-/activeadmin

So, to get multiple term search working, follow steps 1 and 2 above, and include my fork of A.A. in your Gemfile:

```
  gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/d-H-/activeadmin.git'
```

HTH.

If anyone's got a simpler method, please share!

Answer (score 3):

Just add three filters to your model:

```
filter :email_cont
filter :email_start
filter :email_end
```

It gives you a flexible way to manage your search.

[image]

This filter executes next sql code:

```
SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users"
WHERE ("admin_users"."email" ILIKE '%smith%' AND 
       "admin_users"."email" ILIKE '%\.edu')
ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

I expect that exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This is close, but I actually need something that matches multiple queries anyway in the email. Searching at the beginning, middle and end doesn't quite cut it for me. :( Thanks, tho.